# Understanding VBScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel, vba

I have a VBScript that I`m converting to PHP, I hae some part that I don`t understand and don`t know the output of ... Also if possible, provide me with a similar method in HTML/PHP

```
TextBox1.Value = 1#
txtTurnoverIncl = TextBox1
Format(CDbl(txtTurnoverExcl.Text) * _
                             CDbl(txtRoyalty.Text) / 100, "#,##0.00")
If txtTurnoverExcl.Text <> "" Then
Format(Round(.Text * 14 / 114, 2), "#,##0.00")
TextBox1 = Now()
TextBox3 = Date
TextBox4 = Format(MyDate, "dddd")
```

And this function:

```
Private Function SumCashUp() As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp As Double
    For i = 10 To 12
        With Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
            If IsNumeric(.Text) Then
                tmp = tmp + CDbl(.Text)
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    SumCashUp = tmp
End Function
```

I guess thats all.

Comment: That's not VBScript, it's VB. VBScript has no Textbox objects, no Controls and no `As Double` stuff. Tags have been updated accordingly.

Comment: The first block of code you gave is meaningless collection of lines from different places. To understand the meaning post more code. The last 3 lines are illegal, you can't assign date or string value to Textbox object so I guess you miscopied the real code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I have copied every line from a VB  Code I have that is attached to an Excel Sheet. And yes, the first block is a mixture of code lines from here and there.

Comment: @sikas: so what exactly is the question? what line you don't understand?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Every line of the first block. For example, what does this `#` mean in line one. What does the `Format` function and `CDbl` function in line 3? What is `Now()`, `Date` and `Format(MyDate, "dddd")`?

Comment: @sikas - done the best I could, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `TextBox1.Value = 1#` - Assign the value 1 in format Double to the textbox control. (thanks MikeD)
2. `txtTurnoverIncl = TextBox1` - Assigning reference to the control `TextBox` to variable called `txtTurnoverIncl`
3. `CDbl(txtTurnoverExcl.Text)` - Convert the text inside the textbox `txtTurnoverExcl` to *double* i.e. numeric value with decimal point e.g. 2.6 - this is useful if you want to perform mathematical operations on the value for example.
4. `Format(..., "#,##0.00")` - Format number to look like this: `2.60` or `8.25` i.e. with two digits after decimal point.
5. `Round(.Text * 14 / 114, 2)` - The `.Text` means you're inside `With (somecontrol)` block, so it's actually `somecontrol.Text` i.e. taking the Text of the control. Round function will round the number for example `Round(662.791, 2)` will return `662.79` and `Round(662.796, 2)` will return `662.8`
6. `Now()` - Returns the current date and time on the machine where the code is executing
7. `Date` or `Date()` - Like Now() but only with the date, time will be 00:00:00
8. `Format(MyDate, "dddd")` - Get name of the day of week of MyDate, according to the Culture on the machine. For example for Hebrew culture it will return `יום שלישי` for English culture it will return `Tuesday`. In general, Format() given date and string will Format the date according to the string e.g. `Format(Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy")` will return `14/12/2010`

Comment: textbox1.Value = 1# assignes value 1 in format Double .... # is the format identifier for double data type

Comment: @MikeD thanks, that's what I assumed but couldn't find any proof.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard, I don`t think PHP has floats or doubles, all stored in variables `$variableName`, right? How to perform the operation of `CDbl` on PHP? and also the Format and Round? are there any alternates in PHP? Sorry for asking a lot.

Comment: the proof is in Excel VBA Help files .... refer to the "Double Data Type (Visual Basic for Applications)" page ... <quote> The type-declaration character for Double is the number sign (#). </quote>

Comment: @MikeD: I got that part already from your explanation and Shadows. Now I want to know if there are alternates in PHP. I`m a programmer myself, but I didn`t code in VB in more than 4 yrs. I`ve been coding in C++, C#, Java, and PHP.

Comment: @sikas sorry I'm not familiar with PHP.. I'm sure you'll find the answer by searching for "PHP number conversion", "PHP number format", "PHP date format", "PHP Round function" here or in Google.

Answer (score 1):

The last function returns the sum of the values of the textboxes named "Textbox10", "Textbox11", and "Textbox12" in a pretty complicated way. I guess in PHP you would do something like this (assuming you are POSTing a form):

```
function sumCashUp() {
   return (double) $_POST['Textbox10'] + (double) $_POST['Textbox11'] + (double) $_POST['Textbox12'];
}
```

Comment: If I write it as a JS will it look like this? function sumCashUp() { return Textbox10.value + Textbox11.value + Textbox12.value; } ??

Comment: I guess you could use `return document.forms[0].Textbox10.value + document.forms[0].Textbox11.value + document.forms[0].Textbox12.value;`, if you only have 1 form.

Comment: In JS, I like to store the values first, something like `Textbox10 = document.getElementById('Textbox10')` then when I call it, I use `Textbox10.value`. Isn`t that the same you said?

Comment: @sikas yep that's the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all it would be better to analyze what the whole thing is doing (semantically) rather than looking at sequences of code. So the remainder of this post is a bit speculative ....

There are a couple of textboxes displayed on the screen

- `TextBox1` ... initialized with value 1(double), later containing current time (`now()`) (imho a sin in itself - brrrr - hope there is good business logic explanation for this)
- `TextBox3` ... initialized with the current date
- `TextBox4` ... initialized with "something we don't know" - hopefully a date (`MyDate`), and formated as Weekday (`"dddd"`)
- `TextBox10` - `TextBox12` ... seem to be used to calculate a variable `SumCashUp`

we have some more variables which may be textboxes as well (as sometimes we see a .Text added in the code)

- `txtTurnoverIncl`
- `txtTurnoverExcl`
- `txtRoyalty`
- `SumCashUp`

and a code fragment that calculates a 14% margin from a Gross (`*14/114`), rounds and formats the result ... and we have no clue about where this result is used. We can speculate that it may be another form field (because of `.Text`) - maybe txtRoyalty - but we don't know.

Basically all the code fragments are about putting values into textboxes displayed on the screen and/or using the values of that text boxes to compute something (like the SumCashUp or a 14% GM).

So I guess the path to the solution must be

- get the source layout of textboxes
- understand the business logic
- create a HTML page containing a form with similar objects (textboxes, a submit button, etc.)
- write PHP code that implements the business logic - most probably as a reaction to a POST event triggered by a Submit button

You already received a couple of code fragments, but one needs to put this into a greater context, otherwise the code blocks won't help.